# Transferring JSON data from Android app to database via webservice

Tags: android, json, web-services, rest, cloud

I am developing an Android application which logs sensor data and summarizes it, the output being JSON data. This is done in order to have a smaller amount of data to be transferred to the server, since it will be stored on a cloud database. I am building a RESTful web service, in order to do so. I have two options that I am considering right now:

1) call the web service from the Android app for every record to insert it into the database

2) call the web service from the Android app to transfer a whole JSON file and then parse it in the cloud and insert every parsed record in the database

In my opinion, option 2 seems more efficient as there could be 100s of records to be inserted in the database and calling the webservice 100s of time would not be ideal. What is your opinion guys, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer depends on the rate you're collecting sensor data.  If the rate is relatively low (every few seconds) then I would suggest your first option (assuming there is benefit in near-real-time data).
If your sensor data is being taken more often (again, relatively speaking) then your second suggestion makes more sense.
Also, consider connection issues since this is mobile.  Increasing your update rate reduces the chances of loosing data because of a lost connection.  But I can't speak to the criticality of your data.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go with something like option #2.  There is no reason to make your app that chatty.

Comment: What do you mean by chatty?

Comment: @user1135357 By chatty I mean making more calls than is necessary to support your intended use.

Answer (score 0):

@user1135357 - You store data on a cloud database - which cloud database exactly ? Do you already have a specific service for you, or still haven't decided on one ?

Comment: I bought one. Regarding the web service, I created a WCF service and hosted it online

Comment: @user1135357 - Cool. If you are interested, you can also try a solution which you can store JSON objects on the cloud directly from your Android application, or from a web service: [link](http://www.zkbox.com/developers/client/java). You can see on the link how you can use it simply. Please contact me if you want to try it.